# GDP of domestic and foreign economic activities of a country

Tags: gdp, international-trade

Is there an indicator which shows how much GDP of a country is generated by domestic economic activities (e.g. business between food production in Germany and agriculture in Germany) and how much GDP is generated by economic activities of that country with foreign countries (e.g. business between food production in Germany and agriculture in Brazil)?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to segregate value generated by all companies/economic agents that trade with foreign entities? If so, what about value generated by companies who's suppliers are domestic but suppliers' suppliers are foreign?

Comment: I would like to segregate domestic sector transactions and transactions of domestic sectors with foreign sectors.

Comment: The latter is captured in balance of payments accounts. Imports are exactly that

Comment: Thank you for your response! Wikipedia says "The balance of payments (also known as balance of international payments and abbreviated B.O.P. or BoP) of a country is the difference between all money flowing into the country in a particular period of time (e.g., a quarter or a year) and the outflow of money to the rest of the world." However what I want (sorry for not being clear ... none-native speaker here ;-) ), is the difference in all money flowing into and out of the country and the money flowing within the country.

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate domestic economic activity by calculating GDP and subtracting net exports. Any activity that requires dealings with foreign country will be recorded as either export or import. Once you subtract exports and imports from GDP you are left just with domestic activity.